# Reduce Memory Usage of Java Process

Tags: java, .net, memory

I wrote a wrapper application in c# NET that runs when the .jar file is running, closes when the .jar file closes, etc. This was basically to allow for our web panel to be able to query the executable to find out if it was actually running or not.

I have seen some other panels specifically intended for this software that have an option to reduce the memory usage of it when no one is connected. The java application (Minecraft) basically scales the RAM usage based on the size of the player world rather than how many players are connected. When no one is connected, it should be perfectly fine to reduce the usage.

So is there any way to reduce the RAM usage programatically from C# NET for a Java application?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Why not? Because you can't control the Java-Program in that way for two reasons:

- You can't control what the JRE does with it's memory and how the GC is working.
- If `minecraft.jar` requests 512MiB of RAM, he gets 512MiB of RAM. You can't just go all `Hey, there's no one connected so I disallow you to allocate memory` on an application. I mean, you could...but I don't think you want that (that would trigger exceptions and odd side-effects).

**Edit:** The only rather easy way to achieve this behavior would be to change the program. Since Minecraft is not free/open-source software, the only thing you could do is file a bug/feature request. Maybe even with extended information and a layout concept on how to achieve better memory usage.

I mean, I'm pretty sure that this could also be achieved with heavy usage of reflection via a Java program...but things go pretty fast downhill from there.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to tell a JVM to give regular heap memory back to the operating system ... apart from telling it exit completely.

Comment: @baba - because it won't give back memory to the OS.